# Trouble with getting linq values to display correctly in view using view model

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I am trying to display data retrieved from a linq query in a view via a view model. I have a variable set to the linq query and then I am referencing it in an instance of the table in the view model. If I forgo the view model and just return the variable in the return view, I get my desired data. When I try to use the view model, I am forced to call ToString when I reference the linq query variable and instead of my desired result data, I get this TRAIntranet2019.Models.TblShiftInfo which is the table I am querying. And I am changing the model reference at the top of my view for either the view model (when using the view model) or the regular model (when using just the linq variable). Shift target is the current example I'm working on.

```
private TRAKERContext db = new TRAKERContext();

// GET: LandingPageVMs
public IActionResult Index()
{

    var shiftTarget = db.TblShiftInfo.FirstOrDefault();
    //var rvuvalue = db.Tradetail.FirstOrDefault().ToString();



    TblShiftByRadByDate tblShiftByRadByDate = new TblShiftByRadByDate()
    {
        //ShiftName = "Late Night Shift"
    };

    Tradetail tradetail = new Tradetail()
    {
        //Rvuvalue = (double)rvuvalue
        //SignLastName = rvuvalue.ToString()
    };

    TblShiftInfo tblShiftInfo = new TblShiftInfo()
    {
        //ShiftAvgTarget = Convert.ToDouble(shiftTarget),
        Shift_Name = shiftTarget.ToString()

    };

    RadidCrosswalk radidCrosswalk = new RadidCrosswalk()
    {
        RadFname = "Jimmie"
    };

    FacilityCrosswalk facilityCrosswalk = new FacilityCrosswalk()
    {
        FacilityName = "TRA"
    };

    LandingPageVM vm = new LandingPageVM()
    {
        TblShiftByRadByDate = tblShiftByRadByDate,
        Tradetail = tradetail,
        TblShiftInfo = tblShiftInfo,
        RadidCrosswalk = radidCrosswalk,
        FacilityCrosswalk = facilityCrosswalk

    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

Expected output = "The name of the shift"

actual output = "TRAIntranet2019.Models.TblShiftInfo"

Comment: The string `"The name of the shift"` is not present anywhere in your code that I can see.  Why is that the expected output?

Comment: Can you post the relevant class(es)?

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it’s hard to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t understand the question but try to figure out...

- Using ViewModel:

The action on the controller:

```
public IActionResult About()
        {
            TblShiftInfo tblShiftInfo = new TblShiftInfo()
            {
                Shift_Name = "Shift Name Example",
                ShiftAvgTarget = 12345
            };

            LandingPageVM vm = new LandingPageVM()
            {
                TblShiftInfo = tblShiftInfo,
            };

            return View(vm);
        }
```

The view:

```
@model MyWevApp2.Models.LandingPageVM

<h2>Data in ViewModel</h2>

<p>@Model.TblShiftInfo.Shift_Name</p>
<p>@Model.TblShiftInfo.ShiftAvgTarget</p>
```

- Using ViewBag or ViewData.

If you don´t want to use a ViewModel... you can use ViewBag or ViewData. For example:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    TblShiftInfo tblShiftInfo = new TblShiftInfo()
    {
        Shift_Name = "Shift Name Example",
        ShiftAvgTarget = 12345
    };

    ViewBag.TblShiftInfo = tblShiftInfo;

        return View();
    }
```

In the view, you can use the ViewBag:

```
<p>@ViewBag.TblShiftInfo.Shift_Name</p>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but the issue I'm having is more with the linq query than the view model. The shiftTarget var is getting the correct value. I can check it by passing shiftTarget in the return view parameter and using the TblShiftInfo model inside the view. But if I use the view model or even a view bag, instead of getting my expected data (ie the name of the shift) like I get when I pass shiftTarget in the return view parameter, I get TRAIntranet2019.Models.TblShiftInfo, which is just the model I am returning the data from in the linq query. ToString is the only difference between the two.

Comment: mmmm I understand...  the problem is that the result of your linq query is an object of type Shift_Name (instead if could be a null too) and then you are calling ToString() on an object which by default gives you the namespace of that object.

That´s the problem:

Shift_Name = shiftTarget.ToString()

Dont´t use ToString() like this, you should call:

Shift_Name = shiftTarget;

And then you should use the properties or fields in the Shift_Name instance, like this:

<p>@ViewBag.TblShiftInfo.Shift_Name.PROPERTY</p>

Comment: Thanks again! The problem is that if I don't use ToString() I get "cannot implicitly convert type 'TRAIntranet2019.Models.TblShiftInfo' to 'string'" error on shiftTarget inside my new instance of TblShiftInfo. TblShiftInfo tblShiftInfo = new TblShiftInfo()
            {                
                Shift_Name = shiftTarget
            };

Comment: Your answer worked out great with a viewbag, so thanks a million! but I still am having  the same issue when trying to use the view model.